# How to show all system privileges for all users in Oracle database

Tags: oracle

I need a query how to list all system privileges only (not the object ones) which are granted to each user in database. I need listed system privileges whatever they granted thru role or direct.

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Retrieving all user privileges within Oracle can range from a simple task using a basic SQL query to an advanced script, depending primarily on how involved the roles and privileges are configured within the server."

https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/oracle-user-privileges--how-to-show-all-privileges-for-a-user/